# How to input multiple line in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to take input from the user as multiple lines. But when a run the program and write "Hello, my name us umer" here when i enter to write new line. The program runs. I want to write new line. This is my code to read inpput.

```
string text;

    cout<<"Enter the text"<<endl;
    getline(cin,text);
```

How i can input muliple line in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a loop for multiple lines.

```
while(getline(cin,line))
{
  cout << line << endl;
  //do something
}
```

Comment: But my question is how user will run the program? when i enter, the new line comes. How will i know, user enters his all text?

Comment: @Umer: When user enter `EOF`. In linux it's Ctrl-D.

Comment: Thanks buddey. Its ctrl+z in windows.